# Why are nectarine pits different colors?

Tags: fruit

Some nectarines have a dark reddish pit, while others have a much lighter tan color. Why is this? Are they different species?

Answer (score 1):

They are not different species (all nectarines belong to the species peach), they are different cultivars. It is normal for different cultivars of a fruit to look and taste different.